# How can uncheck the first radio button when selecting the second one and reverse when having 2 radio groups?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to archive that if i select the first radio button i should receive value `true` and the second radio button should be unselected and receive the value `false` also in reverse if i select the second radio button i should receive value `true` and the first radio button should be unselected and receive value `false`: Important is that on submit to send 2 parameters on backend True/False for each Radio that is the reason why i have not placed them in the same group

**This is my actual html Component:**

```
  <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-2">
      <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="male">
        <mat-radio-button [value]="true" [checked]="false" [(ngModel)]="male" name="male" (change)="firstRadioChange($event)">Male</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
      <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="female">
      <mat-radio-button [value]="false" [checked]="false" [(ngModel)]="female" name="female" (change)="secondRadioChange($event)" >Female</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
```

**This is my ts:**

```
 firstRadioChange($event){
    console.log($event.value) 
  }

  secondRadioChange($event){
    console.log($event.value) 
  }
```

Comment: Because the backend is expecting 2 parameters so the Male: True/False also the Famale: True/False and in default should be both false because there are part of a filter component @DavidFontes

Comment: Well, the way I would do it, would be, right before sending the data to the server, map my model to the model that the server is expecting and this way I would be able to use just one group.

Comment: @DavidFontes Please share your way on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I have added my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70990742/11755228).

Answer (score 0):

I would simply group the radio buttons, by default only one of them can be enabled.

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1 Male</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2 Female</mat-radio-button>
  <br>
  <br>
  Selected value: {{selectedValue | json}}, send to backend sex as: {{selectedSexObj | json}}
</mat-radio-group>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['radio-overview-example.css'],
})
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  selectedSexObj = { male: false, female: false };
  selectedValue: any;
  onChange(event: any) {
    this.selectedValue = event.value;
    if (event.value == 1) {
      this.selectedSexObj = { male: true, female: false };
    } else {
      this.selectedSexObj = { male: false, female: true };
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qggcqg-qydurn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.ts

Comment: Your code does not solve my problem because if i have to send one parameter to the backend this would be the case  but the problem is that the backend is expecting 2 parameter so Famale: True/False and Male: True/ False and on default should be both false because they are part of a filter @Joosep.P

Comment: Okay, to be fair that wasn't mentioned before. However I have updated my code for you. Either way, `onChange()` function should be quite clear on how to read radio button value changes. I can not implement your "backend object" for you without seeing it first. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this example**

Radio-buttons should typically be placed inside of an  unless the DOM structure would make that impossible (e.g., radio-buttons inside of table cells). The radio-group has a value property that reflects the currently selected radio-button inside of the group.

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgufpa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.html

Comment: Your code does not solve my problem because if i have to send one parameter to the backend this would be the case but the problem is that the backend is expecting 2 parameter so Famale: True/False and Male: True/ False and on default should be both false because they are part of a filter

Comment: the first time they are both false. if you check male the male: true and female: false and if you check female then female: true, male: false

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes on your attempt.

- You are using both **Template Driven-Forms** and **Reactive Forms**, you should use just one on each input or else they might interfere with each other. In the demo below, I have used the **Reactive Forms** approach.
- You used 2 `mat-radio-group` but you should use just one for the UI, then before sending the data, you modify the data according to your needs.

Here is the relevante code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mb-2">
  <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" [formControl]="gender">
    <mat-radio-button value="male"> Male </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="female"> Female </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="other"> Other </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
gender: FormControl = new FormControl('male');

submit() {
  const responseToServer = {
    male: this.gender.value === 'male',
    female: this.gender.value === 'female',
    other: this.gender.value === 'other',
  };

  this.http.post('your-server-url', responseToServer);
}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-14tu4k?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Im not familiar with angular, are you submitting  the form to server side in the end? If so you could use one radio group with both options as ui but sending it as a first options true/false data, and for second option could use hidden input which you set manually on change of radio group to opposite value of radio group.